# Fullcalendar with events - unable hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to show FullCalendar with events and hide/show this calendar whenever the user focuses on some input. Currently it looks like:

```
$("input[name='start']").focus(function () {         
    $('#calendardep').fullCalendar(options).slideToggle();
);
```

But this is rendering only prev/next icons.

P.S. Probably I should use `'render'` but I don't know how to mix this with my options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fullcalendar doesn't render correctly when hidden. The workaround is to call `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');`.

So:

```
$("input[name='start']").focus(function () {         
    $('#calendardep').fullCalendar(options).slideToggle();
    $('#calendardep').fullCalendar('render');
});
```

or

```
$("input[name='start']").focus(function () {         
    $('#calendardep').fullCalendar(options).slideToggle(400, function(){
        $('#calendardep').fullCalendar('render');
    });

});
```